# how to use route useFactory method in angular 16

Tags: angular, authentication, routes, guard

I m using Angular 16 standalone route where I want to handle navigation for

1. Doctor
2. Hospital

and both should have / post login.

like below is my routes

app.routes.ts

```
{
        path: '', //  Hospital portal
        loadChildren: () => import('@pages/hospital/hospital.module'),
        canMatch: [authGuard({ requiresAuthentication: true, role: accountType.hospital })],
    },
    {
        path: '', //  Dcotor portal
        loadChildren: () => import('@pages/doctor/doctor.module'),
        canMatch: [authGuard({ requiresAuthentication: true, role: accountType.doctor })],
    },
```

app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideRouter(routes, withComponentInputBinding(), withPreloading(SelectivePreloadingStrategyService)),
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([serverErrorInterceptor, jwtInterceptor])),
        provideAnimations(), // required animations providers
        provideToastr(), // Toastr providers
        .....,
        importProvidersFrom(
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                isolate: true,
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                    deps: [HttpClient],
                },
            }),
        ),
        { provide: TitleStrategy, useClass: TemplatePageTitleStrategy },
        {
            provide: ROUTES,
            useFactory: () => {
                let authService = inject(AuthService);
                let customizedRoutes: Routes = [];
                customizedRoutes.push({
                    path: '',
                    canMatch: [authGuard({ requiresAuthentication: true })],
                    loadChildren: () =>
                        authService.hasRole() == 3
                            ? import('@pages/hospital/hospital.module')
                            : import('@pages/doctor/doctor.module'),
                });

                return [...customizedRoutes, ...routes];
            },
            multi: true,
            deps: [AuthService]
        },
    ],
};
```

My canMatch guard

```
export const authGuard = (options: AuthGuardOptions = defaultAuthGuardOptions()): CanMatchFn => {
    return (_: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
        const authService = inject(AuthService);
        const router = inject(Router);
        if (options.requiresAuthentication && authService.isAuthenticated) {
            return true
        }
        return options.requiresAuthentication
            ? router.createUrlTree(['/auth/login'], {
                  queryParams: {
                      returnUrl: segments.map((s) => s.path).join('/'),
                  },
              })
            : router.createUrlTree(['/']);
    };
```

I have tried in angular 14 and found solution for angular 14

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/angular-dynamic-routing-299c04ca75b1

https://netbasal.com/conditionally-load-a-module-using-angular-router-aff022923850

but in angular 16 I stuck how to use useFactory method

I have read this as well [How to lazy load module based on some condition using useFactory in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598323/how-to-lazy-load-module-based-on-some-condition-using-usefactory-in-angular) but how to implement in 16, I am looking for

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Look for a solution for the same need.

Comment: I faced the same scenario and when I had the router as empty array [] in the provideRouter it is working fine. 

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: appRoutesFactory,
      deps: [ProjectService],
      multi: true,
    },
    provideRouter([], withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation()),
    ....
}

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario and when I had the router as an empty array [] in the provideRouter it worked fine.

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [
   {
     provide: ROUTES,
     useFactory: appRoutesFactory,
     deps: [ProjectService],
     multi: true,
   },
   provideRouter([], withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation()),
   ...
]
```